# Epplus - Cannot change cell value or cell header

Tags: epplus

I have a problem when change the value of a cell. Here is my code:

```
FileInfo newFile = new FileInfo(file); ExcelPackage pck = new ExcelPackage(newFile);

        var wsData = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Absent Employee List");
        var dataRange = wsData.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(
                from s in emps
                orderby s.EmployeeCode
                select s,
                true, OfficeOpenXml.Table.TableStyles.Medium2
                );
        wsData.Cells[2, 4, dataRange.End.Row, 4].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-mm-yyyy"
        wsData.Cells[2, 5, dataRange.End.Row, 5].Style.Numberformat.Format = "dd-mm-yyyy";

        wsData.Cells["A1"].Value = "Employee Code"; // [1, 1]
        wsData.Cells["B1"].Value = "Full Name"; // [1, 2]
        wsData.Cells["C1"].Value = "Department"; // [1, 3]

        dataRange.AutoFitColumns();

        pck.SaveAs(newFile);
```

When I open the file after creating, the header of A1, B1, C1 didn't change. Did i miss something? thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
wsData.Cells[1,1].Value = "Employee Code";
wsData.Cells[2,1].Value = "Full Name";
wsData.Cells[3,1].Value = "Department";
```

This is what worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in the library, it has been fixed in a prior release.
You can find the bug description as well as a workaround here:

https://epplus.codeplex.com/workitem/15245

```
ExcelTable excelTable = this.worksheet.Tables[0];
excelTable.Columns[1].Name = "Test";
```

Comment: This bug was fixed in version 4.0.4